# File can't be moved by root on OS X

Tags: macos, permission, filesystem, unix

I tried to move a few files to a subfolder on OS X. One refused to move. It said `Operation not permitted`. I tried again as root:

```
$ sudo mv file subfolder/
mv: rename file to subfolder/file: Operation not permitted
$ sudo mv file filex
mv: rename file to filex: Operation not permitted
$ lsattr file
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on file
```

I tried `lsattr` on other files; all files I tried gave me the same message: `Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading...`

Coming from Linux, I did not know about flags so here is the output of `ls -leO@ file`:

```
$ ls -leO@ file otherfile
-rwxrwxrwx  1 eeytan  staff  uchg 79549 Nov 11  2010 file
-rw-r--r--  1 eeytan  staff  -     5071 Sep  7 02:37 otherfile
```

I tried the OS X Disk Utility; it said there were no errors on my disk. What's going on here?

Comment: `lsattr` isn't a standard OS X command; try `ls -leO@` instead. Also, what volume is the file on? Try `mount` to see what attributes the volume is mounted with.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, it seems you're on the right track. ls -leo@ says that file is the only one with the "uchg" attribute, which sounds a lot like "unchangeable" to me.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Sounds like the file is locked to me, which is why the uchg attribute is appearing. You should be able to use the following command to remove the locked attribute:

```
chflags nouchg file
```

or right-click the file in the Finder, click "Get Info" then uncheck the "Locked" checkbox

Comment: Ha! It looks like you answered your own question just as I was posting this answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hadn't noticed the lock icon! I have to use Finder sometimes rather than sticking to the terminal :P

Answer (score 97):

For people stumbling upon this in an OS X 10.11+ era (El Capitan or newer): [Apple has added a whole new layer of security in OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really). They have taken away some privileges from root. The file you are trying to modify has a `restricted` flag. Only `restricted` processes which are signed by Apple will be able to modify these files. However, you can disable this security system by booting in recovery mode and disabling it in a Terminal by doing: `csrutil disable`.

Alternatively, you can also just start Terminal in Recovery Mode and delete the file there. Or even try booting in a Linux environment with HFS+ support (at least if you're not on APFS yet) to change the file.

Comment: What does the csr in csrutil stand for?

Comment: I believe it was Benjamin Franklin who said "Those who sacrifice ease of use for security deserver neither". Or something.

Comment: Do you mean start the computer in Recovery Mode?

Comment: Try the other answer first.

Comment: FYI you can determine if a file has the `restricted` flag with `/bin/ls -lO`

Comment: People make inappropriate sacrifices to get insufficient security because of unclear ideas (and implementations) of security.  For instance, the OS gives code *all abilities of the user*.  So if there's a virus inside a utility or library used by root, it can do anything... so they restrict what root can do.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
chflags -f -R nouchg directory
```

on a higher level directory to stop this problem.

Comment: FWIW: I had this problem `zsh: locking failed for /Users/me/.zhistory: operation not permitted: reading anyway` and running this command on my home directory fixed it

Answer (score 3):

I had a file I couldn't delete in terminal:

```
$ sudo ls -leO@ foo@example.com/Documents/.%cb_defense/cb.doc
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel  - 41984  1 Mar 11:20 foo@example.com/Documents/.%cb_defense/cb.doc

$ sudo rm -rf foo@example.com/Documents/.%cb_defense/cb.doc
rm: foo@example.com/Documents/.%cb_defense/cb.doc: Operation not permitted
```

What worked for me was opening Finder and deleting the containing directory whole. The way I understand it, Finder deletes directories as a unit entirely disregarding their contents, so it's not subject to the same restrictions as regular `rm -rf`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, and I discovered that the folder the file was in was locked. So make sure that's not true. Do 'get info' on the folder in the finder, and make sure the locked checkbox is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

Under OS 10.15 this worked for me:

1. Recovery mode: command + R
2. Utilities -> Terminal
3. rm -r /path/to/file/or/dir/to/remove (The -r alone worked for me -- If you need it rm -rf force mode)
4. Reboot

Comment: `-f`doesn't force anything, it just answers some permission questions with `y` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

A previous answer said to use:

```
chflags -f -R nouchg directory
```

There are two different attributes that prevent changing a file.  "uchg" prevents the user from changing the file; "schg" prevents the system from making a change.  Use ls -le0@ to see which is your problem, or use apple-I: if "locked" is checked but not greyed out, then "uchg" is set. If "locked" is checked AND greyed out, then "schg" is set.)  If "uchg" is set, the previous answer will work.  If  "schg" is set, then do this instead:

```
chflags -f -R noschg directory
```

Answer (score 1):

### Before using arcane commands, confirm your System Preferences

Terminal may not have permission to access your `present working directory`.

1. Note your path (e.g. in Terminal, type `pwd`).
2. Visit `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Files and Folders`
3. Confirm there is a check mark next to any volumes and directories that appear in your path.

If Terminal has permissions and the command still gets an error, check the solutions provided in other answers.

Comment: That was my problem - thanks! VSCode and the terminal inside didn't have permissions.

Comment: Mac OS 10.13.6 (High Sierra): no "Files" under Privacy.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old topic but I don't see this thread addressing my symptom so I thought I'd post another opinion.

I had this happen to an external drive that had been functioning perfectly on a Snow Leopard iMac, which got upgraded to El Capitan along the way.  Earlier this year, I took that drive and put it in a new Windows 10 box which was running Paragon HFS for Windows.  I copied hundreds of GB of files ***FROM*** Windows ***TO*** HFS+ on that drive and plugged it back into the iMac.  Everything worked fine, except one shell script I had that staged files for backup encountered this uchg issue.

In short: files and folders created under El Capitan or Windows 10 using Paragon HFS, when moved back to a Snow Leopard box, the "locked" radio box will NOT be checked when you select `Get Info` in the Finder.  However, others' suggestions worked fine for me:

- verify that's the issue by running `ls -leO@` (that's a capital oh) on a suspect file
- as root, run `chflags -R nouchg` on the parent directory (there's no -f in Snow Leopard)

It'll work, just don't expect the exact same visual cues if your drive has gone between operating systems or if you use Paragon HFS.

Comment: chflags -f -R nouchg directory does work
thanks