# root permissions

Tags: permission, macos, root

After I installed el Capitan, Little Snitch started complaining about `gamed` trying to phone home. Research in the net revealed various suggestions, including

- logging out from the Game Centre
- using `launchctl unload`
- `sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.gamed Disabled -bool true`
- adding `<key>Disabled</key><true/>` to gamed's plist
- rename the `gamed` image
- etc.

OK. I wasn't logged into the Game Centre. `launchctl unload` isn't pervasive across reboots (nor is the cruder `killall -9 gamed`). `sudo default write...` had no effect.

So I sudo'ed into `/System/Library/LaunchAgents` and tried to edit `com.apple.gamed.plist`. Try as I would, I couldn't get write permission for the file. The same happened when I tried to rename the `gamed` image.

What has Apple done to permissions? There don't seem to be any special ACLs on `/System/Library/...`, but root cannot change files for which root has `rw` permissions. (This explains presumably why `sudo default write...` had no effect.)

Has anyone else seen this? Is there any way round it?

Steve

Comment: It seems to be that : http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really

Comment: It is indeed that. Thank you. I was coming at it from my `gamed` problem, so I didn't conduct the appropriate searches. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X 10.11, El Capitan, introduced [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) (SIP).

The contents of `/System` and a few other paths [are now protected](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/193379/1860) and can not be edited. Even `root` user can not edit the contents of these paths.

You [can disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-max-os-x-el) but it is generally not recommended:

> 1. Reboot your Mac into Recovery Mode by restarting your computer and holding down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> until the Apple logo appears on your screen.
> 2. Click Utilities > Terminal.
> 3. In the Terminal window, type in `csrutil disable` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 4. Restart your Mac.