# How do I delete useless Apple Apps on OSX?

Tags: applications, mail.app, macos, root

I tried using terminal with `sudo` or `su`, while I do `rm -rf` to Photos.app, Chess.app, Mail.app, DVD Player.app, iBooks.app, but it said *Operation not permitted*.

How can I delete these apps?

(OS X version is 10.11.1)

Comment: Maybe you should look it up before you do it. El Capitan has SIP (sometimes called rootless). I wouldn't recommend deleting Mail.

Comment: on 10.11.0 i can do it, and no problem at all

Comment: Why delete them, they don't take that much space? And I doubt that you have been able to delete them while running any public version of El Capitan (unless you've disabled SIP).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to delete the "useless" apps pre-installed on my Mac?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65169/is-it-possible-to-delete-the-useless-apps-pre-installed-on-my-mac)

Comment: Situation regarding deletion of standard applications changed with El Capitan, don't think it's a duplicate as such. The reasons why deleting them is a bad idea haven't changed though.

Comment: Related:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211922/how-do-i-remove-or-disable-the-photos-app-in-el-capitan

Answer (score 4):

Being OS X El Capitan (10.11) has, from what I understand, the same System Integrity Protection as the current version, macOS High Sierra (10.13), I think the steps are the same. You can delete at least some of the applications. I haven't tried them all but I deleted Maps, Chess and DVD Player.

First, you need to boot into Recovery Mode. Hold `CMD + R` after the boot chime. From there you can go into the Terminal and type `csrutil disable`. Reboot. This disables System Integrity Protection ***and is not recommended to keep disabled***. If you want to live on the edge though, go for it.

After booting back into OS X/macOS I was able to `sudo rm -rf <Application Path>` without any errors.

You can always re-enable SIP after you make your changes.

*Note 1*: I deleted iTunes once but a system update later put it back on.

*Note 2*: You cannot easily get deleted applications back because you cannot download them, to my knowledge.

*Note 3*: If you are just sick of looking at them in Finder, you can hide them by adding a hidden flag to the folder. SIP has to be disabled for this too. I used `sudo chflags hidden /Applications/App\ Store.app/` to hide the App Store from Finder.

*Note 4*: Certain OS features may depend on apps being present so be wary of what you delete.