# How to install certificates with Mono on Rootless El Capitan

Tags: macos, sip, sound-volume

As follow up question for [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really):

How do I install global certificates on a Rootless El Capitan for mono?

Mono uses the path `/usr/share/.mono/certs`, which isn't allowed anymore (see refered post).
Does someone knows where I could store those certificates other then `~/.config/.mono/certs`?

It is not a problem for us to install the certificates in the config folder, but it is a minor annoyance, because all new users on those devices will have to run the installer, instead of only the first user.

Answer (score 2):

Although this post is quite old, maybe an answer is still helpful.

Mono's new cert-sync might help:
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/3.12.0/#cert-sync

> Mono users on Linux no longer need to run mozroots to get SSL working. A new command, cert-sync, has been added to this release, which synchronizes the Mono SSL certificate store against your OS certificate store
>
> If you want to invoke the tool manually (e.g. you installed via make install, not packages) use
>   `cert-sync /path/to/ca-bundle.crt`
>
> On Debian systems, that’s
>   `cert-sync /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`
>
> and on Red Hat derivatives it’s
>   `cert-sync /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`
>
> Your distribution might use a different path, if it’s not derived from one of those.

Comment: Hi Worp! We try to add additional info from links, as it improve readability and insures against link rot. Could you add whatever parts you think are necessary from your link?

Comment: That is a very valid request. Thank you for mentioning. I will improve it right away.