# Dtrace script newproc.d stopped working after upgrade, because of missing proc:::exec-success probe

Tags: macos, script, dtrace

I'm trying to run:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/newproc.d
```

which suppose to snoop new processes as they are executed, but it fails with the error:

> dtrace: failed to compile script /usr/bin/newproc.d: line 22: probe description `proc:::exec-success` does not match any probes

This is on OS X 10.11.2 and as far as I remember, this was working before the upgrade.

It seems new OS X doesn't have anymore `proc:::exec-success` probe as I've checked by:

```
$ sudo dtrace -l | grep proc:::exec-success
```

Failing code of that script (note: this was provided by the system, I haven't changed it):

```
proc:::exec-success
{
  print_pid[pid] = 1; /* This pid emerged from an exec, make a note of that. */
}
```

Is that probe was removed or renamed to different probe? Maybe I could activate it somehow? Otherwise what I can use instead?

Comment: My hunch this is same issue as the following message: probe description fbt::hfs_vnop_read:entry does not match any probes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because of the "Rootless" feature in El Capitan.

You can disable this feature by rebooting into recovery mode and running the command `csrutil disable` (and you can similarly reenable it with `csrutil enable`).

There is a great explanation over at this Ask Different question: [What is the “rootless” feature in El Capitan, really?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) The second answer addresses Dtrace directly.

Answer (score 1):

To be even more secure, you can run:

```
csrutil enable --without dtrace
```

but this is **not intended for production use** according to Apple.