# El Capitan Remove Finder from Application Switcher (cmd tab)

Tags: macos, mac, finder

I'm having trouble removing the Finder icon from the application switcher in El Capitan.  The [guides](http://dzello.com/blog/2012/02/12/remove-finder-from-the-app-switcher-in-mac-osx/) seem to be all from 2012 - I get permissions errors (even using `sudo`) when I try to update `Info.plist`.

Is there a way to edit `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Info.plist`, or a completely different way to remove the Finder that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The file is protected by System Integrity Protection as outlined [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209705/93229).

By disabling SIP you will be able to edit the info.plist again.

So boot to Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> while booting.

- Open Terminal.app (menubar -> Utilites -> Terminal)
- Enter `csrutil disable`
- Reboot your Mac
- Edit the file */System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Info.plist*
- Reboot again to Recovery Mode and enable SIP again: `csrutil enable`
- Reboot your Mac

---

You should also be able to edit the file directly after booting to Recovery Mode without disabling SIP:

```
/Volumes/name_of_main_volume/usr/bin/nano /Volumes/name_of_main_volume/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

---

You may have codesign Finder.app afterwards:

```
sudo codesign -fs - /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/
```