# Can't write to /usr even with sudo

Tags: terminal, macos, php, sudo

Here's my problem:

```
sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
```

...should let me run as root and modify `/usr` & `/usr/share` directories, but I get this:

```
Below is a suggested file layout for your new PEAR installation.  To
change individual locations, type the number in front of the
directory.  Type 'all' to change all of them or simply press Enter to
accept these locations.

 1. Installation base ($prefix)                   : /usr
 2. Temporary directory for processing            : /tmp/pear/install
 3. Temporary directory for downloads             : /tmp/pear/install
 4. Binaries directory                            : /usr/bin
 5. PHP code directory ($php_dir)                 : /usr/share/pear
 6. Documentation directory                       : /usr/docs
 7. Data directory                                : /usr/data
 8. User-modifiable configuration files directory : /usr/cfg
 9. Public Web Files directory                    : /usr/www
10. System manual pages directory                 : /usr/man
11. Tests directory                               : /usr/tests
12. Name of configuration file                    : /private/etc/pear.conf

1-12, 'all' or Enter to continue: 
Unable to create PHP code directory ($php_dir) /usr/share/pear.
Run this script as root or pick another location.
```

Why is `sudo` failing to give me root privilege? *Note: *I am in the wheel group, though that should not have anything with this funny `sudo` behaviour.

```
Gabbar-Singh:~ anadi$ id anadi
uid=XXX(anadi) gid=XX(staff) groups=XX(staff),0(wheel)
```

Answer (score 15):

You are trying to install in `/usr` which is protected by [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) (System Integrity Protection), a feature introduced with 10.11 (see 
[What is the "rootless" feature in El Capitan, really?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) for details).

Use `/usr/local` instead, which is the location intended for user-side installations.

Comment: yeah except I *need* to link to /usr/include or I can't compile with gcc 4.9!

Comment: You’ll have to disable SIP then I guess.

Comment: Old response, but why can't you just tell GCC where to find the include files?  That's what the '-l' option is for.  PHP as root... <shudder>