# How to reenable System Integrity Protection

Tags: macos, sip

How do I reenable System Integrity Protection, after using `csrutil disable` from the Recovery OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "rootless" feature in El Capitan, really?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really)

Comment: If the answer is not `csrutil enable`, then explain why?

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of disable is enable, so: `csrutil enable`

At the present time there is no manual page for `csrutil` i.e. `man csrutil` doesn't provide any help, however executing the *command* without an *argument* displays its internal help as shown below.

```
$ csrutil
usage: csrutil <command>
Modify the System Integrity Protection configuration. All configuration changes apply to the entire machine.
Available commands:

    clear
        Clear the existing configuration. Only available in Recovery OS.
    disable
        Disable the protection on the machine. Only available in Recovery OS.
    enable
        Enable the protection on the machine. Only available in Recovery OS.
    status
        Display the current configuration.

    netboot
        add <address>
            Insert a new IPv4 address in the list of allowed NetBoot sources.
        list
            Print the list of allowed NetBoot sources.
        remove <address>
            Remove an IPv4 address from the list of allowed NetBoot sources.
$
```

Comment: Technically, `csrutil clear` also works.