# Trying to set boot-args with nvram gets "general error" on Sierra

Tags: kernel-extensions, nvram

I'm trying to temporarily disable KEX signing enforcement on my MBP since my company's VPN client (GlobalProtect) is failing the signature check now.  This started yesterday when I did the OS upgrade to Sierra yesterday.

The solution *should* be running this command:

```
sudo nvram boot-args=kext-dev-mode=1
```

The problem is that I am getting the following response, and I can't figure out what it means or what to do about it (meaning I can't connect to my company network, too).

```
nvram: Error setting variable - 'boot-args': (iokit/common) general error
```

Does anybody have any ideas of things I could try or otherwise look at to track down the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: According to https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT206871 it looks like you need to be booted to Recovery to change that

Comment: That was indeed what was necessary.  If you would care to post an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.  Sadly, the setting did not fix my VPN problem, but that's another thing entirely....

Comment: ah, OK - will do. I wasn't certain but it seemed relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Apple KB : Prepare your institution for iOS 10 and macOS Sierra](https://support.apple.com/HT206871)

> ...you must use the nvram command to properly set boot-args NVRAM variable. Starting with macOS Sierra, you must be booted to the recovery partition to run this command.

Comment: This did not work with my Sierra.  However, the `csrutil` option below did!

Answer (score 9):

The kext signing restriction was integrated into [System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) starting in El Capitan, and as a result the old disable flag no longer works. But there's a new way to do it: boot in recovery mode, and run the command `csrutil enable --without kext`. I haven't tested it, but my understanding is that this will turn off the kext requirements, while leaving the rest of SIP enabled. If that doesn't do it, try `csrutil disable` to turn SIP off entirely.

Comment: I take it running just `csrutil enable` again will re-enable it for kext?

Comment: @eduncan911 I haven't specifically tested, but that should do it. If in doubt, use `csrutil status` to check. See [Apple's developer note on Configuring System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html).

Comment: I disabled `csrutil` yet the nvram error persists.

Answer (score 3):

I got the similar issue and resolved the with the help above solution.Thanks..

1. Get into Recovery Mode by restarting and holding down <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> until Apple logo appears.
2. In the top menu click `Utilities > Terminal`.
3. In the Terminal window type:

   ```
   csrutil enable --without kext
   ```

   and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Then restart the Mac.

Answer (score -3):

You need to apply that when in recovery mode. Enter in Recovery mode and then apply the following in the terminal:

nvram boot-args="serverperfmode=1 ncl=262144"

Then, reboot. After rebooting, check the parameter on the terminal via nvram -p

Comment: Both of these boot-args are related to network performance and have nothing to do with kext signing.