# Restarting in safe mode without using the shift key under Mojave

Tags: macos, startup, safe-mode

I'm trying to restart my MBP (now running Mojave) in safe mode, and for whatever reason holding down shift isn't doing the trick (this complaint is scattered across the internet). Apple [offers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) this alternative for cases in which you don't have a keyboard:

> ```
> Access the command line by opening Terminal remotely, or logging into the computer using SSH.
> Use the following Terminal command:
> sudo nvram boot-args="-x"
> ```

Unfortunately, when I run this command I get `nvram: Error setting variable - 'boot-args': (iokit/common) not permitted`. Googling this error gets me a [pointer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/256145/60655) to this bit of info:

> ...you must use the nvram command to properly set boot-args NVRAM
>   variable. Starting with macOS Sierra, you must be booted to the
>   recovery partition to run this command.

Booting from the recovery partition sounds even harder than getting into safe mode, so it appears I am back to square one. Are there any other ways to get to safe mode?

Comment: What happens when you attempt to boot into recovery by restarting, and holding command-R at the chime?

Comment: @David the OP already answered that

Comment: @Buscar웃 The OP said "Booting from the recovery partition sound even harder than getting into safe mode, so it appears I am back to square one." While this suggests the OP may have tried booting into recovery, it doesn't actually say that. Did s/he? We don't know.

Comment: @David so do you have the process for booting in to safe mode from recovery mode, so to explain to the OP what to do.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I don't — I'm not a programmer — but the OP says s/he knows what to do once in recovery mode: "...you must use the nvram command to properly set boot-args MVRAM variable. Starting with macOS Sierra, *you must be booted to the recovery partition to run this command.* It's just not clear the OP tried to boot into recovery.

Comment: does it work using external keyboard ?

Comment: Using a _different_ external keyboard as suggested by @Buscar웃 works!

Comment: Great, lets make that an answer for others to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with MBP's internal keyboard and Mojave **not** Restarting in Safe mode using Shift key, can sometimes be resolved using *External* keyboard instead.