# Not able to write a file with root

Tags: root, vi

I am trying to write to a `vim` file, `fortran.vim`. I gave myself access to root following [these](https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT204012) guidelines. I also saw [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948441/vim-cant-save-file-e212), but the answers did not help.

```
sh-3.2# ls -l fortran.vim
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  4043 Sep  9  2010 fortran.vim
sh-3.2# whoami
root
```

root seems to have read/write access to the file, and I am indeed logged in as root. Any idea what the problem is here?

**Update after comments:**

1. `:w!` doesn't work
2. I am in directory `/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/`
3. Running `ls -dl` returns: `drwxr-xr-x  178 root  wheel  6052 May  1  2014 .`

Comment: You don't actually need to enable the root user, `sudo -s` from any account with admin privileges gives you a root shell as well. But this is not directly related to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files in `/usr` are protected by SIP, see [What is the "rootless" feature in El Capitan, really?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) for details. `vim` should be able to read config files from user-writable directories as well, `man vim` has the details.

Comment: mhm I'm getting to hate any apple product more and more... so much restrictions! Thanks