# Mac OS/X won't let me mkdir /usr/share/tomcat6, even as root

Tags: macos, sudo, root

Running MacOS Sierra (10.12.6)

```
me $ sudo su root
sh-3.2# bash
bash-3.2# pwd
/usr/share
bash-3.2# mkdir tomcat6
mkdir: tomcat: Operation not permitted
bash-3.2# chmod g+w /usr/share/
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/share/: Operation not permitted
bash-3.2# chflags nouchg /usr/share/
bash-3.2# mkdir tomcat
mkdir: tomcat: Operation not permitted
bash-3.2# chmod g+w /usr/share/
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/share/: Operation not permitted
```

I have a web app that expects to find log files in /usr/share/tomcat6/logs/.  Since such a directory doesn't exist, I'm attempting to create /usr/share/tomcat6, and then make a soft link from there (called logs) to the actual logs directory.

How do I defeat OS/X and get my way?

Comment: try https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/

Comment: I have tomcat installed, it's just not in the location this webapp wants

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's because the `/usr` folder, with the exception of `/usr/local`, is protected by System Integrity Protection (SIP).

Check [this Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) for more details on SIP. [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) gives details on how to disable SIP and more info.

Answer (score 8):

Locally-installed software belongs in `/usr/local`, not `/usr`. This has been a good idea roughly forever, and starting in OS X El Capitan, this is enforced by [System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really). It's possible to disable SIP, but really it's better to do things right and use `/usr/local/share` instead.

Comment: what about standard path like `/usr/src?` I cannot create it either

Comment: @AlexeiS The same organization applies; sources you're installing locally belong in /usr/local/src (which you should be able to create).