# iotop on High Sierra

Tags: macos, bash, high-sierra, dtrace

I seem to have issues with `iotop` on High Sierra, googling it I find no useful information. The output is garbled and almost unusable.

I have SIP disabled for dtrace (I know "I'm not suppose to do that", but it worked fine on previous version of OS X, i.e. `> crsutil enable --without dtrace`).

Example output:

```
2017 Oct 16 11:46:25,  load: 2.45,  disk_r:   2520 KB,  disk_w:      0 KB

  UID    PID   PPID CMD              DEVICE  MAJ MIN D            BYTES
    0    182      1 mobileassetd     ??        1   4 R             4096
    0    653    340 scep_daemon      ??        1   4 R            81920
    0    153      1 sandboxd         ??        1   4 R           167936
    0    304      1 mds_stores       ??        1   4 R           831488
120215604   3950      1 IDECacheDeleteAp ??        1   4 R          1490944
    0      0      0                  ??        1   4            1495040
    0      0      0                  ??        1   3            8474624

dtrace: 3060 dynamic variable drops with non-empty dirty list
dtrace: 2000 dynamic variable drops with non-empty dirty list
dtrace: 192 dynamic variable drops with non-empty dirty list
```

The issues as I see them are the `dtrace: xxx dynamic drops`, missing data (there are processes missing) and last the fact that the indentation is messed up. Googling does not bring me closer to the answer.

The only reasonable connection I can find is that the buffer is overflowing (due to disk activity) and to change the buffer policy with the following:

```
#pragma D option bufpolicy=ring
```

But since `iotop` is already compiled I have a hard time doing any changes to it. Or is the osx / apple version of `iotop` available somewhere so I can rebuild it with necessary changes?

And just for completeness, I built the `gnu` version of `iotop` but it wouldn't run and complains that my linux kernel is too old ^^

Anyhow, found this as well: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208185/173331 , and the answer details that Apple is doing some funny shit and hiding processes from dtrace, and in effect I might not solve the "all processes are not showing up" issue.

(apparently I don't have enough reputation on apple.stackexchange.com to create an "iotop"-tag)

Comment: `sudo iotop` in e.g. Mavericks looks pretty the same. Please add an  example with an expected/usable output.

Comment: @klanomath Updated the question a bit.