# How do I grant root access to user files in Mojave?

Tags: permission, mojave, root, rsync

I upgraded my laptop to Mojave. For years, my backup strategy has included using rsync (MacPorts rsync 3.1.3) to copy files to a file server. This stopped working properly, now showing some errors indicating permission problems with `opendir` and `get_xattr_data`, specifically with certain `~/Library` folders.

I use `launchd` to run `rsync` inside a script located in `/usr/local/bin`.

As part of my troubleshooting, I went into `Terminal` and `su`'d to root. Then `cd`'d to my user's `~/Library` and tested access in some of the folders. The system reported `permission denied`.

Through Security & Privacy, I gave `rsync` Full Disk Access, but that didn't resolve the issue.

I'm assuming this is an issue resulting from Mojave's security or privacy settings as I've never seen `root` not have permission to files. In order to resume my backup processes, I need root/launchctl to be able to access files.

What has changed in Mojave that is limiting `root`'s access?
How do I mitigate this limitation as it relates to `rsync`?

---

The possible duplicate seems to confirm the need to adjust settings in Security & Privacy, but so far adding `Terminal` and `rsync` to the list of allowed apps does not allow the backup to succeed. I'm working to add the script I use to run the backup, and will adjust my question when I get that tested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What and how does macOS Mojave implement to restrict applications access to personal data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers)

Comment: Doesn't yet appear to be a duplicate, but it does confirm I may be on the right track regarding settings under Security & Privacy. I tried adding Terminal, and while that does give `root` permission, it doesn't address the `rsync` (which is run from a script) part of the issue. I'm trying to figure out how to add a custom script to the Security & Privacy settings.

Comment: Are you running the script manually or is something else running it such as cron or launchd?

Comment: As (sort of) stated above launchd. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: You should be able to add launchd. Try going to `/sbin/launchd` in a Finder window and then drag that file to the add application dialog in Sys prefs.

Comment: That didn't work. I then tried adding the script being called by `launchd` and while that seems to be giving `rsync` access, the `--dry-run` appears to be wanting to delete all the contents of `~/Library/Mail` so more testing is going to be needed. I've got to head out of town tomorrow for a couple days, so I'll need to pick this up when I return.

Comment: Which specific directories within ~/Library can you not access?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/332673/69572) among some other places, MacOS Mojave implements additional security protocols that even affect `root's` access to user data.

The solution in the linked question provides the basic method I used to resolve my issue.

For custom-built scripts that will run through `launchd`, the administrator of the computer on which the script is to be run must add that script to `Security & Privacy` to give that "app" permission to access user data.

It was *not* necessary to add `launchd` or `rsync` (in my case) to `Security & Privacy`.

I have not researched if there is a way to do this via Terminal, which it seems would be necessary for those administering a large number of clients.

========

Update: I've also learned that if you add a script, and you later make changes to that script, you need to delete it from the `Security & Privacy`-->`Full Disk Access`, then add it again. Perhaps macOS creates a hash that is checked?

========

Update w/ Catalina: I do not recall if I had `System Integrity Protection` disabled on Mojave, but it appears to be required to be disabled in Catalina. I know `SIP` doesn't have to be disabled for OS versions prior to these.

Disabling macOS `SIP` allowed the script in question to start running again. This is not ideal, so I'll be researching other approaches.

Comment: I could only add the script by dragging it from Finder. It was not selectable when using the + button.

Comment: That is probably the simplest approach.

Comment: I added a shell script to Full Disk Access and it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite an answer to your problem, but it's very similar/related...

When writing a shell script that's run by `cron`, e.g. using `rsync` in a script to backup your files on another server.

You will notice that adding "Terminal.app" to the "Full Disk Access" does not work, because `cron` does not use "Terminal.app".

You could grant "Full Disk Access" access to the `rsync` program, and that solves some of the permission problems, but this is not enough if you need access to:

~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary
~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook

Instead, you should add `cron` to "System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Full Disk Access".

I did this by running `open /usr/bin/`, which opened a Finder window that allowed me to easily drag/drop the `cron` program into the "Full Disk Access" list.