# Give local PHP Full Disk Access in Mojave

Tags: mojave, apache, privacy, php, sqlite

I have a PHP webpage running on the local apache installation.  The page uses shell_exec to access the messages/chat.db via sqlite3.

```
shell_exec("sudo -u ben sqlite3 ~/Library/messages/chat.db \"SELECT ...
```

Before Mojave I got the response correctly, but since updating to Mojave I get:

```
unable to open database
```

When running in the Terminal directly, this same issue occurs and is solved by adding Terminal to the "Full Disk Access" pane in System Preferences.

I can't figure out what I need to add for the PHP page; I've tried everything I can find... sqlite3, apachectl, php-fpm, but nothing has worked.

What do I need to add?

FYI: ben is in the sudoers file

Comment: Do you have some rules in sudoers to support this? What happens if you just try to `ls` the Chat DB from PHP, does this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What and how does macOS Mojave implement to restrict applications access to personal data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers)

Comment: @nohillside - Your correct - I removed a bit to try and make it easer to read - I've added `-u ben` back in!  `ls` also fails.

Comment: @JBis - This is different; the answer on that question describes the "Full Disk Access" process I mention, but I'm after the specific application to add...

Answer (score 2):

You are possibly doing it incorrectly.

First of all, `sudo` typically requires a password to be typed, and that won't happen via a Web app.

Second, the **_www** user doesn't get to use `sudo`. That's a big security hole. Don't even think of modifying **sudoers** to allow it.

What you should be doing instead is allow the **_www** user (the one the webserver runs as) access to the `chat.db` file, like this:

```
sudo chgrp _www ~/Library
sudo chgrp _www ~/Library/messages
sudo chgrp _www ~/Library/messages/chat.db
chmod g+rx ~/Library
chmod g+rx ~/Library/messages
chmod g+r  ~/Library/messages/chat.db
```

Comment: Changing the group `~/Library` belongs to is dangerous. There might be other processes/applications which rely on this folder being in the same group the owning user is.

Comment: +1 Good answer, although I do agree with @nohillside, there are better ways to give `_www` permission. You should also mention that they shouldn't *even think* of making the web process (apache/php) run under root.\

Comment: Will this work?  I'm nervous about messing with permissions which I have to unpick.  I'd missed in my question that I'm running as a user in the sudoers file - that user has access to the chat file; but not (for example) via the terminal without adding Terminal to the Full Disk Access list; so surly this is not a user permission issue?  BTW - This worked before the Mojave update

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a non-Mojave system to verify, but with Mojave `~/Library` has rather restricted access rights:

```
pse@Mithos:~$ ll -d . Library Library/Messages Library/Messages/chat.db
drwxr-xr-x@ 137 pse  staff      4384 Nov 11 09:11 ./
drwx------+ 139 pse  staff      4448 Oct  8 20:52 Library/
drwx------   13 pse  staff       416 Sep 27 17:47 Library/Messages/
-rw-r--r--    1 pse  staff  12169216 Nov 15 20:08 Library/Messages/chat.db
```

So while in theory any user can read `chat.db` nobody besides the current user can actually access the directory it resides in.

If you don't worry about others getting access to the file run

```
chmod o+x ~/Library
chmod o+x ~/Library/Messages
```

to allow any user to access files within `Messages`. They still won't be able to access other directories or list the content of `Messages`.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem - PHP still can't see the file

Answer (score 0):

Not the correct answer really, but the only sensible solution I could come up with.

I've written a simple Mac App based on [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer) that can serve the database content without using PHP/Apache/etc...

That App can be given Full Disk Access and everything works.