# "Operation not permitted" for root when trying to ls or chmod -R /Users/user/Desktop

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, permission, catalina

"user" can't do it either. Permission of Desktop/ is set to 700 and owned by "user". Here's the sderr output for `ls -R` command in the home directory:

> **ls: Desktop: Operation not permitted** 
>   ls: AddressBook: Operation not permitted 
>   ls: CallHistoryDB: Operation not permitted ls:
>   CallHistoryTransactions: Operation not permitted 
>   ls: com.apple.TCC:
>   Operation not permitted 
>   ls: com.apple.sharedfilelist: Operation not
>   permitted 
>   ls: CloudKit: Operation not permitted ls:
>   com.apple.ap.adprivacyd: Operation not permitted 
>   ls: Calendars:
>   Operation not permitted 
>   ls:
>   com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider: Operation not
>   permitted 
>   ls: com.apple.Home: Operation not permitted 
>   ls:
>   com.apple.Safari: Operation not permitted 
>   ls: com.apple.news:
>   Operation not permitted 
>   ls: Cookies: Operation not permitted 
>   ls:
>   HomeKit: Operation not permitted 
>   ls: IdentityServices: Operation not
>   permitted ls: Mail: Operation not permitted 
>   ls: Messages: Operation
>   not permitted 
>   ls: CoreSpotlight: Operation not permitted 
>   ls:
>   PersonalizationPortrait: Operation not permitted 
>   ls: Safari: Operation
>   not permitted 
>   ls: Sharing: Operation not permitted 
>   ls: Suggestions:
>   Operation not permitted

Comment: [Transparency Consent and Control (TCC)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers) is blocking it. This is based on the app (Terminal), not the user (/root) account. You need to grant Terminal full disk access in System Preferences -> Security & Privacy pane -> Privacy tab.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add Terminal to the list of apps that have Full Disk Access in the Privacy pane of System Preferences > Security & Privacy.

Unlock the padlock in the bottom left, and drag the Terminal app icon onto the window.

[image: Privacy pane]

Comment: I'm on Catalina and I confirm only giving permission to the Desktop was needed. I get no more error message.

Comment: I've seen this form of answer several times, and while it does work it makes me wonder. Does giving an app full disk access mean another user using Terminal.app can bypass any security restrictions? Is it like chmod 4755 where it overrides or does it just give Terminal.app the _option_ of accessing something that it still needs lower level permissions for?

Comment: @synthesizerpatel No, it's not "root": it just removes the additional security layers that macOS has. owner/permissions still apply.