# Any other Terminal / shell based options to strip all ACLs and extended attributes from a folder?

Tags: terminal, catalina, bash, permission, zsh

I'm having some trouble deleting some folders that contain nothing and have no processes or kexts utilizing them (`lsof | grep path_element`).  When I try to delete them (as root) I get:

```
root@hostname /# rm -fr /path/to/folder
rm: /path/to/folder: Operation not permitted
```

Even after executing the following to strip ACLs / extended attributes, I still cannot rm -fr the folders:

```
sudo chmod -RN /path/to/folder
sudo xattr -c -r /path/to/folder
```

Executing `ls` shows no attributes:

```
ls -lea -@ /path/to/folder
```

Any other options to ensure all permissions are stripped and that an `rm` operation as root should work?

Comment: Depending on the location in question, the folders may be protected by [Transparency Consent and Control (TCC)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers) or [System Integrity Protection (SIP)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really). What is the actual /path/to/folder?

Comment: SIP is off and TCC shouldn't really have anything to do with this since this is on a backup volume at a path something like `/Volumes/system_backup_name/private/var/folders/zz/blah/blah/blah`...

Comment: In Catalina, TCC restricts access to removable volumes, so that could certainly be it.

Comment: Have you trying using the command `/System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass`?

Comment: Even running `/System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass rm -fr /Volumes/system_backup_name/path/to/folder` still returns `Operation not permitted`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson well, if you really think that could be it, how do I bypass it? I have Terminal, iTerm + zsh all in Full Disk Access already as I've tried those. Do I need more than just the parental process in there (ie, add `rm` as well)? Is there a way to trigger these sans TCC handling, eg via David's suggestion of using TMSafetyNet's `bypass`, which also fails?

Comment: Solved, needed to use: `chflags -R nouchg,noschg /path/to/folder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit that was stopping the folder from being deleted was apparently flags being set and so the following finally allowed deletion:

```
sudo chflags -R nouchg,noschg /path/to/folder
```