# Service exited with abnormal code: 101 running user agent

Tags: macos, terminal, launchd

Trying to run a user agent:

```
launchctl load myagent.plist
launchctl start myagent.plist
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>myagent</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/me/folder/startmyagent.sh</string>
        </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Also tried using `Program` instead of `ProgramArguments`:

```
<key>Program</key>
<string>/Users/me/folder/startmyagent.sh</string>
```

startmyagent.sh:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
/Users/me/folder/mybinary
#logger "hello" # bonus issue, this (or echo) doesn't show any output in /var/log/system.log
```

I see this in `/var/log/system.log`

```
Mar 11 20:26:40 My-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (myagent[26142]): Service exited with abnormal code: 101
```

I read that it may be something with permissions, I set recursively everything under `/Users/me/folder/` to 777, changed owner to root also (it was initially my user):

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  staff  41651520 Mar 10 15:35 myagent
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 root  staff        92 Mar 11 20:24 startmyagent.sh
drwxrwxrwx  3 root  staff        96 Mar 11 19:25 log
```

I'm able to run the binary successfully if I just call the script directly in the terminal:

```
sh /Users/me/folder/startmyagent.sh
```

I've no idea how to debug this, can't find anywhere a clear meaning of the `101` error (or solution) and can't get the user agent output to show in the logs or terminal.

Comment: Is the script in (or trying to access anything in) a folder that's [protected by TCC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers), like ~/Desktop or ~/Documents? Also, you can add `StandardOutPath` and `StandardErrorPath` keys to your .plist to record any informative error messages it prints as it tries to run. Also, 777 permissions are almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @GordonDavisson today I can't run it at all, keeps saying Load failed: 5: Input/output error on launchctl load myagent.plist and I've no idea why. There's nothing in the logs. I added StandardOutPath and StandardErrorPath but there's nothing there as it appears to not even find the file. Its show the same error if I pass an invalid filename. I don't understand why Apple always has to make these kind of things so obscure. Agree about 777, just to test quickly.

Comment: @GordonDavisson my files are in a custom subdirectory of `~`. I tried moving them to `/Library/Application\ Support/mynewdir/` (and adjusted the path in the plist), but can't test since it can't load. Is `/Library/Application\ Support/` a valid directory?

Comment: `/Library/Application Support/` is a valid directory; depending on the context, you might or might not need to escape the space, so that's a possible source of confusion. I'd recommend putting the .plist file in `/Library/LaunchAgents/`, since that's the standard location, and files there are auto-loaded at system startup (and/or maybe at login, not sure about that). Note that in the `ProgramArguments` array, you don't need to escape spaces in paths.