# The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “/bin/sh: Operation not permitted”

Tags: applescript

When I run Applescript from a working shell script I get an error:
`Operation not permitted`

This is the shell script and it works fine in terminal:

```
sudo /Users/mbp115/Downloads/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2021.8.22/src/ntfs-3g /dev/disk0s3 /Volumes/Bootcamp
```

This is the AppleScript and it gives me an error:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    do shell script "sudo /Users/mbp115/Downloads/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2021.8.22/src/ntfs-3g /dev/disk0s3 /Volumes/Bootcamp" with administrator privileges
    return input
end run
```

The error message is:

```
Syntax error
/bin/sh: /Users/mbp115/Downloads/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2021.8.22/src/ntfs-3g: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: You're probably running into the requirement for special permissions to access personal information (specifically, your Downloads folder). You probably granted this access to Terminal, but not to your script. See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers) (though it's a little out of date).

Comment: Make sure that /bin/sh has Full Disk Access in system preferences.

Comment: ```ntfs-3g``` was added to the full disk access same as ```terminal```. How to add ```/bin/sh```?

Comment: Added /bin/bash to Full disk Access, but still "operation is not permitted" .

Comment: Added /bin/sh still the same.

Answer (score 1):

This Apple script worked although not as elegant as I wanted. No need for additional access:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        set shell to do script " sudo /Users/mbp115/Downloads/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2021.8.22/src/ntfs-3g /dev/disk0s3 /Volumes/Bootcamp"
        
    end tell
    
    return input
end run
```

After installing the binary in `/usr/local/bin` the original Apple Script worked flawlessly.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/ntfs-3g /dev/disk0s3 /Volumes/Bootcamp" with administrator privileges
    return input
end run
```