# How can I access `~/Library/Messages`?

Tags: terminal, messages, permission, zsh

I'd like to copy *manually* into `~/Library/Messages` to maintain message history.

The folder is owned by the user, not by root:

```
% ls -al ~/Library | grep Messages
drwx------   11 sam    staff   352 29 Jun 12:11 Messages
```

and yet I cannot read the contents

```
% ls -al ~/Library/Messages
total 0
ls: /Users/sam/Library/Messages: Operation not permitted
```

Even though it's unclear why I should need to `sudo`, I try anyway

```
% sudo ls ~/Library/Messages
Password: 
ls: /Users/sam/Library/Messages: Operation not permitted
```

but that fails as well.

How can I access `~/Library/Messages` (on Monterey)?

#### Update

Now `Terminal` can access `~/Library`.

```
% ls ~/Library/Messages
Drafts
...
prewarm.db-wal
```

and I can set aside the existing `~/Library/Messages`

```
% mv ~/Library/Messages ~/Library/Message-set-aside
```

but I still cannot `rsync`

```
rsync -avz /Volumes/bak/sam/Library/Messages  /Users/sam/Library  >> /tmp/messages-log 2>&1
```

as it yields

```
building file list ... done
Messages/
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/Users/sam/Library/Messages" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
*** Skipping everything below this failed directory ***
```

Hints?

Comment: That directory has privacy protection, which is separate from file permissions (see ["What and how does macOS Mojave implement to restrict applications access to personal data?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers)). To access it from Terminal, you'll need to grant the Terminal app access in the Security & Privacy preferences.

Answer (score 2):

That folder has special protection enforced by the kernel for sensitive data. You can open the folder by navigating to it in the Finder. Or you can grant full disk access to the Terminal app in the Security and Privacy preference pane.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to use `rsync` from the command line, not drag-and-drop from the `Finder`.

Comment: The third sentence in the answer tells you how to gain access with Terminal, which should then let you use `rsync`.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri The update incorporates what happens—the symptoms, not the cause.

Answer (score 0):

macOS (or at least `Monterey`) will not let the user `rsync` into
`~/Library/Messages`.

It will, however, let you `rsync` into `~/`, and from there you can drag
the `Messages` folder into `~/Library`.