# Why do I get "operation not permitted" when I try to `ls` the content of Desktop on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, terminal, permission, iterm

I cannot list files in the `Desktop` folder using the terminal:

```bash
Desktop % ls -l
total 0
ls: .: Operation not permitted
```

I have no problems accessing the `Desktop` folder or its subfolders with the Finder app.

OS: Sonoma 14.0 (23A344)
Terminal: iTerm2

I have checked the permissions for the `Destkop` folder and some of its subfolders using Finder's "Get Info" panel (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) and my user has R+W permissions (as expected).

Comment: See ["What and how does macOS Mojave implement to restrict applications access to personal data?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that applications have an additional set of permissions over the user folders.

I had to allow `iTerm2` access to the `Desktop` folder:

System Settings => Privacy & Security => Files and Folders => iTerm => Desktop Folder => Enable

[image]

Comment: Seems a bit "overdone" to me. :)