# Unable to mount read-write in OS Catalina 10.15.4 in Single User Mode

Tags: macos, catalina, mount, single-user

The command `/sbin/mount -uw /` no longer works after I upgraded to Catalina. I've read that this is due to Apple. Is there a new solution to mount to read and write through Single User Mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Catalina uses a new split-volume system for its file system, where system files are stored on a read-only volume, and user-modifiable parts of the filesystem are stored in a separate "Data" volume that's normally mounted read-write (see [this article](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/10/08/macos-catalina-boot-volume-layout/) for more info). But in single-user mode they're *both* mounted read-only.

If you just need write access to the normally-writable parts of the filesystem, you just have to update the mount point for that volume:

```
mount -uw /System/Volumes/Data
```

If you need write access to the normally-read-only volume, things are more complicated. You'll need to:

1. Restart in [Recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) and then either make your modifications there and call it a day, or...
2. Open Terminal (under the Utilities menu in Recovery), run `csrutil enable --without fs` (see [my answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375603/catalina-not-allowing-to-change-read-write-permissions-despite-having-sip-disabl))
3. Restart in single-user mode
4. Run `mount -uw /` and maybe *also* `mount -uw /System/Volumes/Data`
5. Do your modifications
6. Finally, restart back to Recovery and run `csrutil enable` to get the normal system protections back.

Comment: will disabling and then reenabling using csrutil cause any problems/side effects?

Comment: @Albert Temporarily disabling SIP protection shoudn't have any lasting effect after you re-enable it, but the changes you made with it disabled might.

Comment: @GordonDavisson `csrutil enable --without fs` says `Requesting an unsupported configuration.`.

Comment: @xiaoyu2006 That's just a warning message; you should be able to proceed. (Although if you are using Big Sur, the process has gotten more complicated; see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395508/can-i-mount-the-root-system-filesystem-as-writable-in-big-sur)).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is by design. Boot to recovery and choose terminal from the Utility menu.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

Here is an example of when you use terminal app from recovery for things we used to use single user mode to accomplish.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207584

Of course don’t follow all the steps above unless you want to erase a fusion drive equipped Mac, but it shows the steps to get to a command line environment on all OS that don’t work in single user mode.