# I’ve just updated to Catalina. Admin is read only, and I cannot change it to read and write

Tags: administrator

On Macintosh HD info admin is read only. I am the admin, but when I try to change it to read and write I get a message

Comment: And that error message is?

Comment: Are you trying to change permissions to the top level of the system volume? In Catalina, that's a read-only volume, so no changes are possible (and it's also restricted by System Integrity Protection). More info in this question: ["Catalina not allowing to change read/write permissions despite having SIP disabled"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375603/catalina-not-allowing-to-change-read-write-permissions-despite-having-sip-disabl)