# "ls" works, but "ls -l" gives me "Operation not permitted"

Tags: command-line, permission, extended-attributes

There are several folders on my system (Monterey 12.2.1) on which I can successfully run `ls`, but if I run `ls -l` on the same folder I get "Operation not permitted".

I am running these commands as root, and Terminal has full disk access.

I found this because timemachine can't back up these files, and I have no explanation as to why this would happen.

Here's an example:

```
 # ls /private/var/folders/44/26mm0l190mn7sf9xj5gmn3wh0000gp/0/com.apple.routined
dv
# ls -l /private/var/folders/44/26mm0l190mn7sf9xj5gmn3wh0000gp/0/com.apple.routined
ls: dv: Operation not permitted
total 0
```

Permissions and extended attributes on the parent directory seem normal:

```
# ls -ld@ /private/var/folders/44/26mm0l190mn7sf9xj5gmn3wh0000gp/0/com.apple.routined
drwxr-xr-x  3 aaroni  staff  96 Jun 24  2020 /private/var/folders/44/26mm0l190mn7sf9xj5gmn3wh0000gp/0/com.apple.routined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to back up those folders.  /var is transitory data.

Comment: @MarcWilson, `/var` is *nominally* transitory.  In practice, a lot of the data is pretty long-lived, and some of it (such as log files) can be useful to back up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **I can successfully run ls, but if I run ls -l on the same folder I get "Operation not permitted".**

**Difference between `ls` and `ls -l`**

`ls` displays the name of the files/directories contained in a directory, while `ls -l` displays a lot of more information (excerpt from `man ls`):

```
If the -l option is given, the following information is displayed for each
file: file mode, number of links, owner name, group name, number of bytes
in the file, abbreviated month, day-of-month file was last modified, hour
file last modified, minute file last modified, and the pathname.
```

Usually, read access to the parent directory should be enough to get this information, but in this particular case (SIP enabled and `datavault` flag set, see below), it's not.

For example, to get the number of links, you need to know the inode number. You can get that information with `ls -i`, and you will see it fails for a number of files and directories (and consequently `ls -l` will fail for those files/directories, too):

```
ls -i  /private/var/folders/51/y66nwk4x1b700xgy1fs5d_9w0000gq/0/

ls: com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
ls: com.apple.SharedWebCredentials: Operation not permitted
ls: com.apple.lockoutagent: Operation not permitted
ls: com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
ls: dmd: Operation not permitted
18693497 com.apple.ScreenTimeAgent  18701711 com.apple.corespeechd      18688786 com.apple.icloud.searchpartyd  18687284 com.apple.progressd
18693950 com.apple.Spotlight        18687828 com.apple.dmd          18687147 com.apple.notificationcenter   18691540 com.apple.routined
18688254 com.apple.bird         18702008 com.apple.dock.launchpad   11150084 com.apple.pluginkit
```

On the other hand, `ls` simply displays filenames, and that information can be retrieved for all files.

**Why doesn't `sudo ls -l` work?**

`sudo` let's you run commands as `root`:

```
$ sudo whoami
root
```

but `root` is no longer an almighty user: since OS X 10.11 "El Capitan", its powers are restricted by [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/HT204899) (SIP):

> System Integrity Protection restricts the root user account and limits the actions that the root user can perform on protected parts of the Mac operating system.
>
> Before System Integrity Protection, the root user had no permission restrictions, so it could access any system folder or app on your Mac. Software obtained root-level access when you entered your administrator name and password to install the software. That allowed the software to modify or overwrite any system file or app.
>
> System Integrity Protection includes
> protection for these parts of the system:
>
> - (...)
> - /var

so `/var` is one of the protected folders that `root` has no longer unrestricted access to.

But there's more going on: disabling SIP makes these files accessible to `root` and to the owner. All files that couldn't be read have the extended attribute `com.apple.rootless` set, which marks them as being [protected by SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/193379), but they also have the `datavault` flag enabled, for example:

```
ls -ledD@ com.apple.LaunchServices.dv

drwx------@ 4 jaume  staff  datavault 128 Jan 17 10:35 com.apple.LaunchServices.dv
    com.apple.rootless   27
```

which makes them [unreadable except for apps with the corresponding entitlement](https://mjtsai.com/blog/2018/10/25/mojave-fixes-quicklook-cache-vulnerability-with-a-datavault/) (when SIP is disabled, access is again governed by mode and ownership, as in a traditional UNIX-like file system).

> **I found this because timemachine can't back up these files**

`/private/var/folders` stores transient data and its contents are not backed up by Time Machine.

Comment: Fair enough but this answer does not explain *why* root cannot access these. Normal UNIX permissions convention is that if you have `r` and `x` on a directory, you can get all `dentry` data. So how come OP can get some, but not others? And how come root is permission restricted anyway?

Comment: @abligh Good point, there's a lot going on behind the scenes, with SIP and the `datavault` flag restricting access, even for `root`. When SIP is disabled, access works according to file mode and ownership. As for why the OP can get information on some files, but not others: from checking the source code of `ls` (https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/file_cmds/tree/file_cmds-321.100.11), it seemed that `fts_read` couldn't get the inodes of some files, but I can't give a conclusive answer (`dtruss` didn't help much). I've expanded my answer with more information on `root` access and SIP.

Comment: "To access some of this information, you need read access to that file or directory." None of that information requires read access. You just need to be able to call `stat()` on the file.

Comment: @Barmar I agree, `stat()` doesn't require read access to the file, and yet, when the `datavault` flag is set and SIP is enabled, `stat()` (and for that matter `stat`) fail, while `fts_read()` seems to be able to retrieve the filename. I've rephrased the answer to make it clear that I refer to this particular case, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you for this incredibly detailed answer! I'm not sure why timemachine is attempting to back up /private/var (and various other folders containing unreadable files), but this gives me a good starting point.

Answer (score 6):

The "dv" you're seeing here is, as I recall, "datavault". Apple has in general been moving away from standard Unix conventions to a more "rootless" system based on entitlements instead of user permissions. My guess is that the files you're looking at belong to `routined` (a daemon which tries to figure out things you do often) and you would need an entitlement in order to access them. There are a number of other directories protected in this way, for example everything in `/System` as well as e.g. iMessage database files.