# Cannot view or manipulate one of MacOS's "special" folders in Terminal

Tags: terminal, finder, permission, folders

I've somehow managed to cut myself (and the superuser???) off from my `~/Downloads` directory in the Terminal.

- I did not purposefully enter any Unix commands to change permissions or access.
- I *did* install a download helper in my Brave browser at around that time and use it to download an audio file to that directory.  (The audio file ended up being corrupted.)
- I *can* still access and manipulate the folder using Finder.

Here's how it looks with some context in the Terminal:

```
drwx------+  10 dmg staff          320 Sep  4 22:31 Desktop/
drwx------+  41 dmg staff         1312 Aug  8 07:10 Documents/
drwx------+   4 dmg _lpoperator    128 Sep  9 14:58 Downloads/
drwx------+  79 dmg staff         2528 Aug 29 17:47 Library/
```

Here are a variety of things that are now weird about the directory in the Terminal.

```
~$ /bin/ls Downloads/
ls: Downloads/: Operation not permitted

~$ chgrp staff Downloads/
chgrp: Downloads/: Operation not permitted

~$ sudo /bin/ls Downloads/
Password:
ls: Downloads/: Operation not permitted

~$ sudo chgrp staff Downloads/
chgrp: Downloads/: Operation not permitted

~$ xattr Downloads/
xattr: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'Downloads/'

~$ cd Downloads/

~/Downloads$ /bin/ls -al
total 0
ls: .: Operation not permitted

~/Downloads$ cd ..

~$
```

I can't recall whether the Unix group of the directory was `staff` or `_lpoperator` before whatever I did to the directory (but I'm a member of both groups anyway).

Notice that I can `cd` to the directory okay and also that I can access the `..` pointer to `cd` back out.

In 27 years of using Unix systems and 20 years of OS X experience, I've never encountered a permissions issue that I couldn't fix with `sudo` in the Terminal.  I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.

If the directory weren't "special" in MacOS's eyes, I would just erase it and create a new one.

P.S. This is on Monterey 12.5.1 on a brand new M1 MacBook Pro.

**::EDIT::**

Thanks to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/437601/456579) that was suggested in the sidebar, I just learned about System Integrity Protection.  So, in an effort to solve the problem (without actually figuring out what went wrong) I turned SIP off.

With SIP off, as `root` I was able to delete the Downloads directory and then recreate it.

However, before I deleted the directory I was able to list its contents.  To reiterate, with SIP off *before "fixing" anything* I was able to take an action that I was *not* able to do with SIP on.  This suggests that whatever I broke somehow caused SIP to think that listing the contents of `~/Downloads` in Terminal was not an approved action.

In any case, I have resolved the problem (through brute force), but I still don't understand what I did to cause it in the first place.

Comment: You changed everything in $HOME to 700 for some reason?

Comment: No, my `umask` is 0077, so dirs end up 700, regular files end up 500, and executable files end up 700.

Comment: Have you granted the Terminal app access to your Downloads folder (see ["What and how does macOS Mojave implement to restrict applications access to personal data?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers))? Also, does the Downloads folder have any other unusual permissions or properties (check with `ls -leO@ ~`)?

Comment: It looks like your edit is the "answer" to your original question. Please make sure to place your solution as an "answer" as opposed to editing your question.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes, the Terminal app has access to Downloads.  The Downloads folder currently has this property: `com.apple.macl     72`, but remember that I've already deleted and recreated it.  I no longer have access to the problematic version.